# Counting functions and subsets

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, divisor-counting-function

I'm having troubles understanding how to tackle this problem about coefficients. By equating the coefficients of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{2n} = (1+x)^n(1+x)^n$ prove that $$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum^n_{i=0}\binom{n}{i}^2$$I started by doing an induction on n by stating my base case to be n =0 which is true. Now I have as my I.H. to be let n = k and assume is true so now I'm trying to prove it for n = k+1. My problem is trying to correlate the information given with the problem  to begin solving the problem. A starting point or a hint will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to use induction. Just equate the coefficients of $x^n$ as the directions say. By the way, this is a special case of Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: What I'm having a bit trouble understanding is how $\binom{n}{i}x^i * \binom{n}{n-i}x^{n-i} $ comes into question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use induction. We can show it straightforward. In order to do so, it's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
  [x^k](1+x)^n=[x^k]\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i=\binom{n}{k}
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
>   [x^n](1+x)^{2n}=[x^n]\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{i}x^i=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
>   [x^n](1+x)^{2n}&=[x^n](1+x)^n(1+x)^n\\
>   &=[x^n]\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j\tag{2}\\
>   &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}[x^{n-i}]\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}x^j\tag{3}\\
>   &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}\tag{4}\\
>   &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2\tag{5}
>   \end{align*}
>
> Since we have selected in (1) and (5) the same coefficient $[x^n]$ the validity of the binomial identity
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2
>   \end{align*}
>   follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand $(1+x)^{2n}$ according to the *[binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* and select the coefficient of $x^{2n}$.
- In (2) we expand each factor $(1+x)^n$
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and use the rule $$[x^k]x^jA(x)=[x^{k-j}]A(x)$$
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-i}$ from the righthand sum
- In (5) we use the symmetry $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{n-i}$